# How can I redirect file request matching a folder to another link?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is the content of my `.htaccess` file on my site server.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

I would like to block access to file requests in the folder `notforyou` (example of a request below):

```
http://my-cool-site.com/wp-content/uploads/notforyou/path/to/file.pdf
```

What rewrite conditions and rules can I add so that any file request from the folder like this can be redirected to another web page?

I added something like this at the top of the `.htaccess` but the files in `notforyou` can still be accessed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/notforyou/(.*)$ http://example.com/ [NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code into your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|pdf|png)$ http://www.yoursite.com/hotlink.gif [R,L]
```

You’ll need to change you yoursite.com to your domain name, and change hotline.gif to an image file on your server that explains hotlinking is disabled on your site.

Comment: This I guess is a way to block general hotlinking. What regex do I need to make this apply recursively to my `notforyou` folder.

Comment: Check this  rewrite rule :-RewriteRule notforyou/(.*)$ - [F,NC,L]  ( or ) RewriteRule notforyou/(.*)$ http://example.com/noimage.jpg [R,NC,L]